# jQuery progress bar load until page redirects

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I have a website that has some affiliate links, when the link is clicked the user is taken to a temporary page on my site, there is a hidden affiliate link on this page that is clicked using jQuery after 1 second.

I want to show the jQuery loading bar progress until the page redirects to the affiliate link.  How can I do this?

Comment: Have you made any code yet we can take a look at? We like code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try something like,

```js
// for 10 intevals only and after that your affiliate link is clicked.
var i = 0,
    parts=20,
    interval=1000/parts;// for 1 second, I used 1000, you can change accordingly

var c = setInterval(function() {
  if (i++ > parts-1) {
    clearInterval(c);
    alert('link clicked now');
  }
  p=Math.floor($('.progress').width()/parts);
  
  $('.progress-bar').width(p+$('.progress-bar').width());
}, interval);
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.progress-bar {
  width: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

You can also try https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/ and https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: thanks this is working but only loads about 20% of the bar and then redirects - maybe my error somewhere

Comment: The alert is showing, the bar stops at 10 - 20% and then redirects

Comment: I changed parts = 5 and this is working better, loads 60-70%

Comment: parts is used to divide the overall progress into sub progress and using 1 will load the progress in one go only, so use 20 is better to view. You can change it by 5 or 10 also and it works fine at my end